# Using dlsym and adding -ldl to flags

Tags: c, unix, dynamic-linking

I am trying to write a C program that uses `dlysm`, and I keep getting an undefined reference to dlysm. I think I need to set my `-ldl` flags but I have no idea how to do this.

I am very new to linux and setting variables. If this is what I need to do can someone help me out with the commands?

Answer (score 3):

`-l` library options are used at link time.

If you compile just one source file (`gcc -o program program.c`), then you both compile and link in one go. Just add the `-ldl`.

If you compile multiple object (`*.o`) files, and then link them together, specify the `-ldl` option to the linker (`ld`).

See also `man ld` and `man cc`

Comment: I get this error 

user@ubuntu8041:~$ gcc -Wall -g -o mymalloc mymalloc.c -ldl
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.4/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: This says that you didn't define a main() function; the runtime library requires a main to run your program.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `-ldl` as a parameter to the compiler.

Example:

```
gcc myprog.c -o app -ldl
```